# NETPLAN not acepting settings

Tags: networking, netplan, static-ip

[yaml setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ2ua.jpg) I have the following netplan layout and it keeps coming up with the error

IP address shown here as xxx

ethernets:
check indentation^

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
    addresses: [xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xx]
    gateway4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8,x.x.x.x]
```

As far as I am aware the spacing is all correct. (2 spaces for each indent)
Not sure what I am missing.

Any assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: @steeldriver everything after `enp0s8:` in fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/24
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [10.10.10.1, 1.1.1.1]
```

The correct spacing is found in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Hi so to make sure i get this right then under enp0s8 we still follow the indent rules and place the - under the 'p' (2 spaces in) then leave a space for the IP address and then go gateway and nameservers go back under the 'a' in address. Trying that now :)

Comment: still comes up with the followin "Error in network definition. Expected Mapping (check indentation) ethernets:^

Comment: The - goes under the second d in 'addresses.' Then one space and then the actual address. Are you using the spacebar or tab? Netplan won't accept tabs. What is the result of: `sudo netplan generate --debug` ?

Comment: I have it half running now where the debug is fine. It was also reading in the static.yaml and the 50-cloud which were set incorrect so i have deleted these and also added dhcp4: no in the cfg. The netplan has now been generated and applied without issue. Once I connect the network cable it will ping itself only. It will not ping anything else on the network or its gateway or anything on the internet. This is frustrating but i do not which to use the old ifup/down and need to get my head around this :)

Comment: I would certainly try a reboot. Without knowing the addresses, at least the last part; e.g. xxx.xxx.12.1 or xxx.xxx.12.155/24, etc. it is hard to troubleshoot further.

Comment: :) IP xxx.xxx.221.5/27 gateway xxx.xxx.221.4 nameservers include google 8.8.8.8

Comment: Rebooted but still the same

Comment: Just adding an image to the original question so you can see the cfg :)

Comment: Success...... I removed the connection from the switch and firewall and reconnect them. It is now pinging everywhere and running. Many thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

What also helped me:

- using yamllint to identify obvious YAML formatting errors.

  - `sudo apt-get install yamllint`
  - `yamllint /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`
  - Errors like trailing whitespace and extra blank lines can cause issues too
- Comparing the example at `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` and my config at `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

  - `vimdiff /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`