# netplan error when setting static IP

Tags: 20.04, netplan

My config is as so, but when I try to `sudo netplan try` or `sudo netplan generate` it errors.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'

network:
ethernets:
  eno1:
   addresses: [10.18.100.12/24]
   gateway4: 10.18.100.1
   nameservers:
     addresses: [10.18.27.10, 10.17.27.10]
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

It keeps getting stuck on nameservers: it appears, I used no tabs only spaces not sure why its not working.

Thanks

Comment: Your spacing doesn't look correct.  You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1145356/231142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [10.18.100.12/24]
      gateway4: 10.18.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.18.27.10, 10.17.27.10]
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: That worked Thanks!

Comment: All set thanks again.

Comment: @DickyDal Glad I could help you!