# Error when setting static IP

Tags: server, network-manager, internet, vmware, wired

when I install DHCP the network service is normal, but when I set the static IP the network shows a question mark as shown. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 installed on VMware.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NETPLAN not acepting settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145346/netplan-not-acepting-settings)